# AES GCM decrypt Firefox error only: "DOMException: The operation failed for an operation-specific reason", Chromium OK though

Tags: firefox, encryption

I followed former answers from [Webcrypto AES-CBC Decrypt: Operation Error - The operation failed for an operation-specific reason](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51172513/webcrypto-aes-cbc-decrypt-operation-error-the-operation-failed-for-an-operati) and [JavaScript AES encryption and decryption (Advanced Encryption Standard)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51531021/javascript-aes-encryption-and-decryption-advanced-encryption-standard)
and used:

```
iv = crypto.getRandomValues(new Uint8Array(16))
key = window.crypto.subtle.generateKey(
            {
                name: "AES-GCM",
                length: 256,
            },
            false,
            ["encrypt", "decrypt"]
        )
```

to generate the key
and

```
Uint8ArrayEncrypted = window.crypto.subtle.encrypt(
        {name: "aes-gcm", iv: iv, tagLength: 128}, 
        key,
        Uint8ArrayVar)
```

to encrypt and

```
Uint8ArrayDecrypted = window.crypto.subtle.decrypt(
        {name: "aes-gcm", iv: iv, tagLength: 128}, 
        key,
        Uint8ArrayEncrypted)
```

to decrypt

On Chromium 83 (Ubuntu) and Firefox 88, I successfully generate the key, the iv and encrypt.
And on Chromium, it simply also decrypts without problem.`Uint8ArrayDecrypted` is correct ArrayBuffer.

But FF throws the error "The operation failed for an operation-specific reason" and stop there. No `Uint8ArrayDecrypted` returned.

I didn't use `tag`, like in [WebCrypto API: DOMException: The provided data is too small](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66155504/webcrypto-api-domexception-the-provided-data-is-too-small)

Reading https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto/encrypt,
I don't see it uses tag.

Does Firefox need something else specific?

Why the error message is so "generic"? Which operation or specific reason?
With an error so generic, I don't know where to look.

Comment: Runs fine on my machine under Chromium v85, Chrome v90 and Firefox v88. Post the complete script and not just fragments. Probably you make the mistake somewhere else.